# passing userId in Hub of SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Greeting..!, I am making a asp.net chat webApplication using SignalR were I want to keep track of every user and store there actions is database. I use userId to keep track of them. 
My problem is that I don't want to pass confidential data(like userId) from client form to signalR hub.And I know SignalR hub class does not support sessions.
so how can I do that.

I am new to signalR and I googled a lot about this problem but couldn't find any simple answer.

Comment: If your user is authenticated, it should be passed automatically and should be in the context user object.

Comment: But then how can I trace him along with his connectionId and UserId, ConnectionId is generated by hub class and UserId by me. I want to store both of them in one table or list. My purpose is to trace them and allow the message to be passed to users with specific userId.

Answer (score 2):

SignalR supports different ways to authenticate and authorize users:

- Cookie
- Windows authentication
- Certificate
- Connection header

You can find more information about SignalR and security here:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/introduction-to-security

Keep in mind that even though some info might be transferred, there is often an abstraction that does not really let someone map a user to a token or vice versa on anything else than the server.

Authentication and authorization is only a small part of security which goes further by using SSL and to carefully think what you transmit as you already said., etc.

But on some point you need a link between relevant information on your server side application and the caller. This might be a session identified by the cookie after a classic forms based authentication, an hash based header or whatever you want to create. SignalR is flexible so you could think about something like authentication against a different system and pass only a delegation token.

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways to map your userId and the connectionId.
Take a look at [this tutorial on asp.net](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections)