# Push notification with SignalR and SQLDEPENDANCY only to a specific user based on a Criterion sent from the Client itself

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, sqldependency

I have a C# application which sends real-time notification using signalR and SQL dependency.

It works fine with a query not dependant on user.

But now, I want to send notification only to the user for which data have changed (where userid=@id)

**SQL SERVER**

```
USE [BlogDemos]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Messages]    Script Date: 10/12/2019 16:25:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Messages](
    [MessageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [userId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EmptyMessage] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Messages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MessageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Messages] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Messages_Date]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Date]
GO
```

**The Hub *in C#***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MapUsers;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SignalRDbUpdates.Hubs
{
    [HubName("notificationHub")]
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        Int16 MessageID = 0;
        string Message = "";
        string EmptyMessage = "";

        public void Hello()
        {
            Clients.All.hello();
        }



        [HubMethodName("sendNotifications")]
        public string SendNotifications()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [MessageID], [Message], [EmptyMessage], [Date] FROM [dbo].[Messages] " ;

                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MessageID = Int16.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["MessageID"].ToString());
                        Message = (dt.Rows[0]["Message"].ToString());
                        EmptyMessage = (dt.Rows[0]["EmptyMessage"].ToString());
                        Date = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Date"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
            return context.Clients.All.recievenotification(MessageID, Message, EmptyMessage, Date);
        }
        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {


                NotificationHub nHub = new NotificationHub();
                nHub.SendNotifications();
            }
        }
    }**
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(SignalRDbUpdates.Startup))]
namespace SignalRDbUpdates
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();   
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.Auth** (to allow client call from a different server)

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace SignalRDbUpdates
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration { EnableJSONP = true });
        }
    }
}
```

**The client**

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="signalrsql._default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>SignalR SQL Server dependancy Client</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 166px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <script src='http://localhost:210/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>     

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.getScript('http://localhost:210/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.min.js', function () {
            $.getScript('http://localhost:210/signalr/hubs', function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:210/signalr';                
                var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;

            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            notifications.client.recievenotification = function (Id, Message, EmptyMessage, Date)
            {
                // Add the message to the page.                   

                $('#spanId').text(Id);
                $('#spanMessage').text(Message);
                $('#spanEmptyMessage').text(EmptyMessage);
                $('#spanDate').text(Date);
                };
                notifications.client.getValue = function (myId) {
                    notifications.returnValue(1);
                };

            // Start the connection.
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    alert("connection started");
                notifications.server.sendNotifications();
            }).fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
            //$.connection.hub.start();
            });
        });
</script>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <h1>Notifications</h1>

<div>
    <table border="1" style="width: 510px">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Id</td>
            <td><span id="spanId"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Message</td>
            <td><span id="spanMessage"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">EmptyMessage</td>
            <td><span id="spanEmptyMessage"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Date</td>
            <td><span id="spanDate"></span></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</div>




    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I want to query the message Table by adding a Criterion

The Query becomes

string query = "SELECT [MessageID], [Message], [EmptyMessage], [Date] FROM [dbo].[Messages] where userId="+id ;

**the @id will be sent from the client to the server**

How this can be achieved?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Map your users as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections). Might consider pushing users into a single user group. In SendNotifications(), instead of Clients.All send to Clients.User(userid) or Clients.Group(singleusergroupname).

You could also go with Clients.Caller() after the SQL query with userid result, which will only send back to the client that requested it.

Comment: I added user connection mapping as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections, Now I am getting the connection table populated with the connectionIds, but the userId is missing, because I am calling the signalRhub from a client which is ina different server

Comment: You will need to take the userid and pass it over when it connects. Check this SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981580/passing-userid-in-hub-of-signalr

Comment: I am now saving connectionId with userId in sql server, userId is sent through querystring, I have now another problem, please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325162/filtering-data-table-prevents-sql-dependency-to-run